# C#, ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework: cannot get object string value

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I intend to store image file into SQL Server, but I can't get object string value.

`ProductController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "pro_id,pro_name,pro_cat,pro_quantity,pro_unitPrice,pro_barImage")] product product, HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(product.ImageFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(product.ImageFile.FileName);
            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            product.pro_barImage = "~/image1/" + fileName;
            fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/image1/"), fileName);
            product.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);

            db.products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.pro_cat = new SelectList(db.categories, "cat_id", "cat_name",product.pro_cat);
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(product);
}
```

Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.pro_barImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.ActionLink("GenerateBarCode", "Index", new { Area = "BarCode", Controller = "GenerateBarCode" }, new { @Parameter = "value" }) 
        <img src="@ViewBag.BarcodeImage" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" id="ImageFile" name="ImageFile" required />
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

Problem I'm facing :

[image: Cannot get object value]

Entity (`Product` table):

[image: Product Table]

Product.cs :
[product.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuQUo.png)

Comment: Can you please also show the C# entity class?

Comment: I had added as image, because system check shows too many code

Comment: But you added a screenshot of the entity in the database - we cannot see the data types of these columns. Please add the **C# class** ....

Comment: i have done added.

Comment: You are seeing the null error entry because your Bind statement isn't binding the filename from your Product object. But I would second guess saving images to a database regardless. Your database could grow very quickly this way. I'm working on a project right now, and we opted into saving images to amazon s3 in a secure bucket. But you would have better success to save the images locally on the server - separate from the database.